RS Latch: Signal behavior during transition from invalid to valid state
I have read a few of the posts here regarding race conditions as they pertain to the RS Latch, but they don't answer my specific question. I understand that if the latch is given an invalid input like s=1, r=1, it will eventually settle to q and q' being 0 and 0.
What I don't get, however, is what happens when we give the latch its next "valid state". Let's give the gate s=0, r=0, this is where the race condition plays out.
I understand that either q or q' will switch first. Let's say q switches first. This means that the input to the bottom gate with receive a 1. But the bottom gate was also in the act of sending a 1 signal to the top gate as well.
My question essentially is this: at the moment that the top gate's signal reaches the bottom NOR gate, is the signal it was sending (which was a 1, since both inputs were 0 previously) overridden? If not, how does this process actually play out?
Here is a diagram that attempts to explain these thoughts visually:

By "not as far", I meant that the 1 signal on the way to the top gate did not travel as far yet as the top gate (which switched first).
I am more than happy to clarify the drawing or anything about my question further, I really want to understand this.
Thank you!

What are "bottom latch" and "top latch"? Do you mean "bottom gate" and "top gate" of a single NOR-based latch? Perhaps you should add a diagram.

@DaveTweed just added a photo, thanks for the rec

This situation is called "metastability". Wikipedia has a fairly reasonable description of the process
"A simple example of metastability can be found in an SR NOR latch, when both Set and Reset inputs are true (R=1 and S=1) and then both transition to false (R=0 and S=0) at about the same time. Both outputs Q and Q are initially held at 0 by the simultaneous Set and Reset inputs. After both Set and Reset inputs change to false, the flip-flop will (eventually) end up in one of two stable states, one of Q and Q true and the other false. The final state will depend on which of R or S returns to zero first, chronologically, but if both transition at about the same time, the resulting metastability, with intermediate or oscillatory output levels, can take arbitrarily long to resolve to a stable state."
RESUME: Don't create invalid states in digital electronics, results will be bad.
Regarding the shape of transients during metastable transitions/oscillations, you may want to check this nice article on SE, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/607103/117785
And real scope traces can be found here.


thanks, but this doesn't really address my question. i'm most curious about what happens when R returns to 0 slightly before S does, for example.

@pixel It does answer that. If there is more than enough time between the events, it works as expected, if there is less time than enough between the events, anything bizarre can happen. Please also note that the electronics implementing digital circuits are analog and thus real world digital circuits are not ideal, a logic level cannot change instantly between 0 and 1 as there is always a transition between them which is neither and there are always delays between the change in input and the effect it has on output.

+1. Thanks for the useful links.


I understand that either Q or Q' will switch first

Stop right here. That's where the race plays out. The Q or Q' switching first resolves the race. Either Q wins, or Q' wins. The race is over at this point!

Let's say Q switches first. This means that the input to the bottom gate with receive a 1. But the bottom gate was also in the act of sending a 1 signal to the top gate as well.

Yes, but that's not a problem. Gates need time to propagate the inputs to the output. When you change the input to a gate, nothing will happen on the output immediately - only some time later, between picoseconds (in a fast modern CMOS IC) and microseconds (ultra low power sub-threshold CMOS).

My question essentially is this: at the moment that the top gate's signal reaches the bottom NOR gate, is the signal it was sending (which was a 1, since both inputs were 0 previously) overridden?

Of course. It is not really overridden, the NOR gate just does its job in propagating the inputs to the output.
When the top gate's Q=1 - that won the race - reaches the bottom gate, nothing happens immediately. But after a propagation delay the bottom gate will output Q'=0, as it should, as is expected. Nothing special here.

There is a rather simple solution to this SR latch possibly ending up in an invalid state: present it with race-free inputs. This is done by putting e.g. a Seitz arbiter in front of the latch.
A Seitz arbiter looks like below (from this presentation). The size-6 NMOS elements drawn in bold are metastability suppressors. This circuit is also called "MR Go", because it makes things go in asynchronous (clock-free) logic.
The circuit takes the A and B inputs, and will always produce only one active output, even if both inputs are present. When A and B are presented "at the same time", one of them wins the race randomly, and is output on either grantA' or grantB'. Once the winning input becomes inactive, the remaining losing input will propagate to the respective output if it's still active. Once all inputs are inactive, the outputs become inactive as well.

I have put it together on the breadboard using CD4007 CMOS (lots of them to get the size ratios needed), discrete NMOS-only logic, discrete PMOS-only logic, normally open "Form A contact" reed relays (NMOS-like logic), and DPDT armature relays (CMOS-like logic). The idea is rather fundamental and thus is not limited to a particular technology.
Given this ME (mutual exclusion) element, the RS latch becomes:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

+1. Thanks for the presentation slides.
